# JavaScript Object Array Initialization from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, spring, jsp

I need to initialize `data` variable  below from the JSON Object `var p = ${jsonobj};` not exactly sure how to do that in javascript. A little context I'm using this inside a JSP page and passing the JSON Object from a Java Controller using Spring MVC.I tested it and made sure im getting the correct json object just not sure the javascript syntax of initializing it. This page describes what im trying to do http://microbuilder.io/blog/2016/01/10/plotting-json-data-with-chart-js.html however does not show how to do it with a variable

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

    var p = ${jsonobj};
    for (var key in p) {
          if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
          }
        }

    var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                data: [{
                    x: -10,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 10
                }, {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 5
                }]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    </script>
```

This is the JSON Object being passed to the jsp

```
public void testCorrelationTable(List<Test> tests,Model model)
{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    System.out.print(obj);
    SampleStatsCalculator sampleStatsCalculator = new SampleStatsCalculator();
    SampleStatsTabulator sampleStatsTabulator = new SampleStatsTabulator(tests);
    TestStatsTabulator testStatsTabulator=new TestStatsTabulator(tests);
    Map<String, Map<String, Test>> sampleTestMap = sampleStatsTabulator.tabulate();
    TestStatsCalculator testStatsCalculator=new TestStatsCalculator(tests,sampleTestMap);
    Map <Test,Stats> testStatsMap= testStatsTabulator.tabulate();

    Map <Test,Stats> testStatsnewMap=testStatsCalculator.calculateCorrelation(testStatsMap);
    TestVisitor visitor=new TestVisitor();

    model.addAttribute("teststatsmap",testStatsMap);
    model.addAttribute("visitor",visitor );
    model.addAttribute("jsonobj", obj);
    for (Entry<Test, Stats> entry : testStatsnewMap.entrySet()) {
        entry.getValue().accept(visitor);

        obj.put(entry.getKey().getTestId(),visitor.getGroupMean());
        System.out.println(entry.getKey().getTestId()+visitor.getGroupMean());
    }
```

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking, exactly.  Can you clarify?

Comment: instead of data being hardcoded  like this data: [{
                    x: -10,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 10
                }, {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 5
                }]
            }]  I need it to be populated from the variable p

Comment: like `data:p` ?

Comment: Is `${jsonobj}` a Java thing? Also, you should post the content of `jsonobj` (or at least a portion of it)

Comment: I tried  var p = ${jsonobj};



var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data:p
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
    }
});

Comment: but got this error Chart.bundle.js:15809 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hidden' of undefined
    at Chart.bundle.js:15809
    at Object.helpers.each (Chart.bundle.js:9522)
    at Chart.bundle.js:15807
    at Object.helpers.each (Chart.bundle.js:9515)
    at ChartElement.determineDataLimits (Chart.bundle.js:15804)
    at ChartElement.update (Chart.bundle.js:11789)
    at getMinimumBoxSize (Chart.bundle.js:11065)
    at Object.helpers.each (Chart.bundle.js:9515)
    at Object.update (Chart.bundle.js:11076)
    at Chart.updateLayout (Chart.bundle.js:8577)

Comment: I think I need something like  this http://microbuilder.io/blog/2016/01/10/plotting-json-data-with-chart-js.html not sure how to do it with a variable

Comment: @Javasharp - What is the `${jsonobj}` line supposed to be doing, specifically?  The syntax is unclear.

Comment: Its a JSON Object with the following data  when iterated through using  for (var key in p) {
          if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
          }
        }

Comment: it produces the following 1942 -> 1.6989700043360187
1943 -> 1.6989700043360187
1944 -> 1.6989700043360187
 1945 -> 1.6989700043360187

Comment: The 1942-1945 values, are those labels for your chart?  On the site, it looks like those would be assigned to the `labels` array, and the data (1.6989...) would be assigned to the `data` array.  I am wondering if your data is just inaccurately structured for what the Chart object needs.  Can you post the JSON value of *p*?  You can do that by adding `JSON.stringify(p);` to your code.

Comment: {"14":1.4225490200071285,"16":1.4515449934959719,"26":1.5569716761534185,"27":1.6989700043360187,"34":1.4225490200071285,"50":1.6989700043360187,"60":1.6989700043360187,"65":1.5569716761534185,"67":1.5569716761534185,"71":1.6989700043360187} this is what I have from stringify

Comment: Ok fixed the error the graph is shwoing up I maade my json look like this {"x:,60":"y:1.6989700043360187","x:,71":"y:1.6989700043360187","x:,50":"y:1.6989700043360187","x:,26":"y:1.5569716761534185","x:,16":"y:1.4515449934959719","x:,27":"y:1.6989700043360187","x:,14":"y:1.4225490200071285","x:,34":"y:1.6989700043360187","x:,67":"y:1.5569716761534185","x:,65":"y:1.5569716761534185"} any suggestions on why its not displaying?